# How to get all the kinds in the google app engine datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using java to code for GAE, I've read through the GAE Java low level API and can't find any answer to my question yet.

I wanna know if there's a way where I can call a method/do a JDOPL and it returns all the different kinds of entities in my Datastore.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the datastore statistics API:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/stats.html

It looks like the `__Stat_Kind__` statistic will give you the info you want.

Comment: thanks! you're right, i found that link through another forum while waiting for the answer

Answer (score 2):

I found a working solution [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/d13d268242083db6/5bb868b394d09c13?show_docid=5bb868b394d09c13&fwc=1&pli=1). (it doesn't work in local deployment server as of July 9, 2010)

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
PreparedQuery global = datastore.prepare(new Query("__Stat_Kind__"));

for( Entity globalStat : global.asIterable() )
{
    Long totalBytes = (Long) globalStat.getProperty("bytes");
    Long totalEntities = (Long) globalStat.getProperty("count");
    String kindName = (String) globalStat.getProperty("kind_name");
    resp.getWriter().println("[" + kindName + "] has " + totalEntities + " entities and takes up " + totalBytes + "bytes<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Metadata API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/metadataqueries). For example:

```
Query query = new Query(Entities.KIND_METADATA_KIND);
DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

Iterable<Entity> entityIterable = datastoreService.prepare(query).asIterable();

for(Entity entity : entityIterable) {
    System.out.println("Entity kind: " + entity.getKey().getName());
}
```