# How get all kinds in Google Cloud Datastore: java

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

How can I get a list of all kinds in [google cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) using java??

I've checked the [library](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/javadoc), I found methods for get or set kind but I didn't find method to retrieve all kinds of the entities.
Further, all solutions that I found them from searching in google are for GAE and doesn't work for me.

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] and review the [help-center].  You are expected to do basic research, such as a Google search, before posting here.  Also, explain what you've tried so far.

Comment: I find a similar question [her](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209324/how-to-get-all-the-kinds-in-the-google-app-engine-datastore) but it does not work for me because it is for GAE..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [kind metadata query](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/metadataqueries#Datastore_Kind_queries), basically:

SELECT * FROM __kind__